# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Hi I'm new to groovy and I am trying to get the edit type of a tfs changset using jenkins, however, when trying to access the edit type I get this error:

```
13:17:50 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.getEditType() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
13:17:50    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
13:17:50    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
13:17:50    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
13:17:50    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
13:17:50    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
13:17:50    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:66)
13:17:50    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
13:17:50    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
13:17:50    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
13:17:50    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:343)
13:17:50    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
13:17:50    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
13:17:50    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
13:17:50    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

The line it is failing on is:

```
// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet = build.getChangeSet()
def items = changeSet.getItems()

println "Affected Files"
def filez = items.collect{
it.getAffectedFiles()
}
println filez

println "Edit Type"
def edittype = filez.getEditType()
println edittype
```

I know this is a nooby question however I truly am confused what is happening. I tried calling `.toString` thinking it was returning an object that can't be printed however that was not the case.

Comment: I think you're calling `getEditType()` on the collection instead of on the type. Try adding `*.` to your call on `filez`.

Comment: @killjoy this is a correct answer.  Would you post it as an answer for anyone who may come across this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method on the collection instead of the underlying type. Either wrap it in a for loop, add another `collect` or use the spread dot operator (`*.`) to call the method. e.g.

```
filez*.getEditType()
```